# Linear subspaces dimensions (1)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question:

> U and V are two linear subspaces of ℝ⁵, with dim(U) = 4 and dim(V) = 2.
>
> Which of the following statements is **always** true?
>
> ▢ V ⊂ U
>
> ▢ U + V = ℝ⁵
>
> ▢ dim(U ∩ V) ≤ 2
>
> ▢ dim(U ∩ V) = 0

---

Using the Grassmann Formula I have:

```
dim (U) + dim(V) = dim(U ∩ V) + dim(V + U)
```

so:

```
dim(U ∩ V) + dim(V + U) = 4 + 2 = 6
```

---

I have excluded the second option (in a not-math-way), `U + V = ℝ⁵`, because it could happen only if `dim(U ∩ V) = 0`, but this is another option, that would eventually take precedence (there is only a single right answer).

---

Then I do not know how to continue.

How can I exclude the other options to find the right answer?

Comment: Are you sure option 4 is correctly typed?

Comment: @egreg No, it's wrong, sorry. I edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can easily find counterexamples to options (1)-(2)-(4), so (3) must be true, and indeed:

$$\dim(U\cap V)\ge3\implies \dim(U+V)= \dim U+\dim V-\dim(U\cap V)\le 2+4-3=3$$

which is absurd since

$$U\le U+V\implies \dim (U+V)\ge\dim U=4$$

Comment: $\dim(U\cap V)\le 2$ because $U\cap V\subseteq V$. No need to use Grassmann's formula.

Comment: @egreg No need to do mathematics, either...anyway, Grassmann's Formula is pretty elementary, and as I began using it I continued with it.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of `U ≤ U + V`. Do you mean `U ⊆ U + V`?

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ The symbol $\;\le\;$ is widely used to denote  that some *subset* is a sub-algebraic structure of something else: if we're in group theory it means subgroup, in linear algebra it usually means subspace, in ring theory it means ideal, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It is clear that the first two options and the last one are not always true. Let $e_i \in \mathbb{R}^5$, where $e_i$ is all zeros except for a $1$ on the $i$-th position.

Counter example of 1st one is: $U = \mathrm{span}\lbrace e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\rbrace$ and $V = \mathrm{span}\lbrace e_1,e_5\rbrace$.

Counter example of 2nd one is: $U = \mathrm{span}\lbrace e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\rbrace$ and $V = \mathrm{span}\lbrace e_1,e_2\rbrace$.

Counter example of 4th one is the same as the counter example for the 2nd one.

The third one is always true

Comment: Ah yes, thanks so much. I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

third option will always be true.

V may or may not be subset of U.

if V is a subset of U then, U+V will not be R5.

last option is not correct as dim(U) gives number, not a set.
this is by elimination.